# Trying to pass down a variable as a prop but it stays at its initial value

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to write a math quiz in React.  The program has three components.  An Index component, a Quiz Component, and a Results Component.

Here's Index:

```
    function Index()
{
    
    let totalCorrect = 0;

    function analyze(){
        let answersArray = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

        for (let i = 0; i < answersArray.length; i++) {
  if(answersArray[i].value == "correct"  && answersArray[i].checked){
    totalCorrect++;
  }

}

 window.location = "/results";
    }

    return(
    <div>
    
    {/* here's the problem, whatever goes into props for results is always what it is
     at the beggining of the program */}
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Quiz a = {analyze}/>} />
          <Route path="/results" element={<Results score = {totalCorrect} />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>

</div>
    )
}
```

Here's Quiz:

```
   function Quiz(props){
    return(
    <div>
    <p>What is 2 + 2?</p>
    <input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "correct" /> 4
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "5" /> 5
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "3" /> 3
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "6" /> 6
    <br />

    <p>What is 2 + 3?</p>
    <input type = "radio" name = "q2" value = "4" /> 4
    <br /> 
    <input type = "radio" name = "q2" value = "correct" /> 5
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "q2" value = "3" /> 3
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "q2" value = "6" /> 6
    <br />

    <p>What is 2 + 4?</p>
    <input type = "radio" name = "q3" value = "4" /> 4
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "q3" value = "5" /> 5
    <br />
    <input type = "radio" name = "q3" value = "3" /> 3
    <br /> 
    <input type = "radio" name = "q3" value = "correct" /> 6
    <br />
    <br />
    <button onClick = {props.a}>analyze</button>
    
    </div>  

    )
}
```

Here's Results:

```
   function Results(props){
    return(
<p>You got {props.score} correct!</p>
        )
}
```

The problem is, as it notes in the comment in Index, the {props.score} always shows up as whatever the intial value for "totalCorrect" was, even though its only after looping through the answersArray that the url changes.  So, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`totalCorrect` is not state and is being updated through JavaScript assignments which will not trigger re-renders. As you are using function components, use the `useState` hook.

```
let [totalCorrect, setTotalCorrect] = useState(0);

function analyze() {
  let answersArray = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (let i = 0; i < answersArray.length; i++) {
    if (answersArray[i].value == 'correct' && answersArray[i].checked) {
      setTotalCorrect((prev) => prev + 1);
    }
  }

  window.location = '/results';
}
```

Please also note the callback function as the argument passed to `setTotalCorrect`:

```
setTotalCorrect((prev) => prev + 1);
```

As this setter function is in a `for` loop, the callback is necessary, as without it, one invocation of your `analyze` function will only ever increment `totalCorrect` by 1, even if the loop invokes it multiple times:

```
setTotalCorrect((prev) => prev + 1); // setTotalCorrect(0 + 1);
setTotalCorrect((prev) => prev + 1); // setTotalCorrect(1 + 1);
setTotalCorrect((prev) => prev + 1); // setTotalCorrect(2 + 1);
```

```
setTotalCorrect(totalCorrect + 1); // setTotalCorrect(0 + 1);
setTotalCorrect(totalCorrect + 1); // setTotalCorrect(0 + 1);
setTotalCorrect(totalCorrect + 1); // setTotalCorrect(0 + 1);
```

Additionally, you are programmatically triggering a window reload using `window.location = '/resluts'`, which will clear any react state. React Router has a built in hook for navigating programmatically - the `useNavigate` hook. This has to be used in a `BrowserRouter` context so your `analyze` function will need to me moved further down the component tree and `setTotalCorrect` will need to be passed down aswell:

```
function Index() {
    let [totalCorrect, setTotalCorrect] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path='/'
            element={<Quiz setTotalCorrect={setTotalCorrect} />}
          />
          <Route
            path='/results'
            element={<Results score={totalCorrect} />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function Quiz(props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function analyze() {
    let answersArray = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (let i = 0; i < answersArray.length; i++) {
      if (answersArray[i].value == 'correct' && answersArray[i].checked) {
        props.setTotalCorrect((prev) => prev + 1);
      }
    }

    navigate('/results');
  }

  return (
    <div>
            
      {/* ...The rest of your component */}

      <button onClick={analyze}>analyze</button>
    </div>
  );
```

This should result in your `/results` page being correctly displayed, and you'll probably notice some speed improvements as well with the omitted window reload.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work.  Same problem.

Comment: Just addressed issue in the answer.